# Spinners with file inputs

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have 7 inputs of files and I want to add spinners to each input. How can I achieve this? I can`t use standart lightning:fileUpload but only lightning:input type="file"

Answer (score 1):

The `lightning:input` aura component is more DIY than `lightning:fileUpload` as you need to provide your own event handlers and Apex code to handle the file upload ([per the documentation on the component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example)). If you want to display a spinner that's easy enough to accomplish by using an `onchange` handler on your component to show and hide a spinner based on the file being uploaded.

```html
<!-- cmp file -->
<div>
    <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-hide" aura:id="spinner">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Uploading...</span>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
    </div>
    <lightning:input type="file" onchange="{! c.handleFileUpload }" />
</div>
```

```js
/* Controller */

handleFileUpload : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    // find the spinner and show it
    let spinner = cmp.find('spinner');
    $A.util.toggleClass('slds-hide');

    // handle the file upload, in callback hide the spinner again
}
```

You may need some additional styling to get the spinner to look its best, but the foundations should be here.